# Error reading characters to matrix

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read text from a file into a char's matrix

I do it this way:

```
 char** crearMundo() 
 {
     ifstream input("C:\\Users\\JhonAlx\\Desktop\\file.txt");

     input >> filas;
     input >> columnas;

     filas += 2;
     columnas += 2;

     char** laberinto = crearMatriz(filas, columnas);

     //Initial fill
     for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
         {
             laberinto[i][j] = ' ';
         }
     }

     //Next two loops will fill only borders
     for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
     {
         laberinto[0][i] = '?';
         laberinto[filas - 1][i] = '?';
     }

     for(int i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
     {
         laberinto[i][0] = '?'; //VS throws error in this line
         laberinto[i][columnas - 1] = '?';
     }

     //Fill actual content of file, omitting borders
     for(int i = 1; i < filas - 1; i++)
     {
         for(int j = 1; j < columnas - 1; j++)
         {
             input >> laberinto[i][j];
         }
     }

     return laberinto; 
}
```

This morning when I programmed it, it was fine, but now it throws this error:

> Access violation reading location 0xFDFDFDFD

Debugging with VS2012 and looking with Locals explorer, I get this text on the ifstream variable:

**input{_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0xcccccccc <
Error reading characters of
string.>
 _Set_egptr=0xcccccccc <
Error reading characters of string.>
...}
 }  std::basic_ifstream >**

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first and last set of loops (the doubly-nested ones), your index limits are set up with respect to `filas` then `columnas`.  However, the middle two (that set the borders) are different and probably wrong.  Note the indices used by your 4 successive loops:

```
laberinto[0..filas-1][0..columnas-1]    -- fill with ' ' (ok: filas, then columnas)
laberinto[0,filas-1][0..filas-1]        -- first borders (bad: filas, then filas)
laberinto[0..columnas-1][0,columnas-1]  -- second borders(bad: columnas, then columnas)
laberinto[0..filas-2][0..columnas-2]    -- read from file(ok: filas, then columnas)
```

The likely cause of your error is overrunning your array bounds due to using the wrong index in the border loops;  the likely fix is to correct that.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't get why second loops are bad, would you mind if you explain a little more, please?

Though I just tested my code with some fixed values for filas and columnas and I get the error again :(

Comment: Just fixed it with **for(int i = 0; i < columnas - 1; i++)** in the second loop, but still I don't really understand why. However, I'm marking your answer as accepted.

P.S.: Again, would you mind if you explain me why, please?

Comment: It looks like the first index should be in `0..filas-1`, while the second index should be in `0..columnas-1`.  However, in the second loop, the second index ranges from `0..filas-1` instead, so if `filas>columnas`, it should get an out of range error.  Also, in the third loop, the first index ranges from `0..columnas-1`, so if `columnas>filas`, it should also get an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method - read the file into a string, and then use c_str() to get the char array.
Example:

```
std::ifstream in("content.txt");
std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
contents.c_str() // The char array
```